# Packer - Parallel Builds - Stop All Builds if One Fails

Tags: ansible, packer

I'm using Packer to create AWS AMIs for deployment.  I build a couple in Parallel for different types of AMIs (Application server, Worker server), and provision them using Ansible.

However, if one of the build processes fail, I want to halt the entire build process for all parallel builds.  Is there a way to accomplish this with packer?

Comment: This would be so usefull.  Not doing it is, expensive!

Answer (score 0):

No.

(Unless you do some strange script that runs last in all builds and wait for all other or times out. But you better do a cleanup script that checks the result of the Packer build and deregister AMI's if one of build failed.)